# saltstack template with grains - bad replacement

Tags: salt-stack

i have created a saltstack template file where i want to replace a variable with the servers ipv4 address:

in my test.template file i have:

```
Address {{ grains['fqdn_ip4'] }}
```

in my init.sls i have:

```
/opt/test/test.conf:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://test/test.template
    - template: jinja
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 0644
```

so the problem is, that the variable is replaced with the correct ip address but not in the correct format:

```
Address ['111.111.111.111']
```

instead of:

```
Address 111.111.111.111
```

so my question: how can i remove the [' and '] form the replacement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

```
Address {{ grains['fqdn_ip4'][0] }}
```

Result:

```
Address 111.111.111.111
```